# Should we remove flutter_launcher_icons after its use?

Tags: flutter

In my app I have used `flutter_launcher_icons` package to update app's launcher icons.

I followed the same steps given at [doc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons). Everything is working as expected.
As this package is a command line tool which works whenever I want to generate or update the icons.

Here are my questions:

1. Should we remove this package after its use?
2. If we are keeping it, does it has any impact on overall app build size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's listed as a dev dependency. which means it only used while you develop your app. when your build your app for production it will not be used. thus,

1. You can remove it after use, but I recommend keeping it. if you need to update the icons again, you will have to add it again.
2. No. it will Not have any impact on App build size. so, keeping it will be the most optimal solution.